# Invoke Android Oficial Home by Application set as home

Tags: android

In my android project, has a tag in the manifest, which allows the user to mark it as default. Whenever the home button is pressed, my application is called, always... I wanted to put a button in my application to call the home of the official Android. Not my application as default. How to do this?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try starting default activity from package com.android.launcher2 :)

try this code

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.launcher2");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Comment: then try other ways of starting activity from com.android.launcher2 package.